# What does [\0-9] mean in regex (perl)?

Tags: regex, perl

```
[\0-9]{10,15}
```

I tried to match phone numbers and ended up writing that regex, and it does match phones containing `+`, `(`, `)` , but I don't understand why.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `^[0-9]{10,15}$`? But in fact you're trying to solve the problem already solved a thousand times. )

Comment: A shorter way to write [0-9] in perl-style regex is '\d': `^\d{10,15}$`

Comment: @TML, actually, those are _not_ equivalent in the presence of Unicode (unless you use the `/a` modifier introduced in 5.14).

Comment: On a side note, [Regexp-Common](http://search.cpan.org/~abigail/Regexp-Common/) has regexes to match phone numbers against.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\0` is a `NUL` byte, the byte `0x0`. The range expresses the range of characters from `0x0` to "9" (`0x39`), which happens to include a bunch of characters like "+". In fact, the range spans the first 58 characters of the ASCII table. See http://www.asciitable.com.

So "##########" would also match your regex.